# What's a word or phrase for someone who has worked hard all their life

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

Someone who has been worn down by a harsh working-life?

Comment: *Powaqqatsi* Serra Pelada harsh?

Comment: @Tim .... what?

Comment: @Dan: LMGTFY :)

Answer (score 5):

I think **haggard** fits the bill here.

HAGGARD

having a gaunt, wasted, or exhausted appearance, as from prolonged suffering, exertion, or anxiety; worn

Answer (score 2):

Such a person would become ***[careworn](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/careworn)***.

> adjective
>
> 1. showing signs of care or worry; fatigued by trouble or anxiety; haggard:
>
> "a careworn old woman."

Reference

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/careworn

Answer (score 1):

I think  ***[toiler](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/toiler)*** may suggest the idea of a hard worker:

> - Toilers are people who work long and hard. Any employer would be grateful to have toilers as employees.
> - If you know that to toil is to work hard, then the meaning of toiler won't be a surprise. A toiler works strenuously; you won't see a toiler hanging out by the water cooler. **People with physical jobs such as construction workers and miners are often referred to as toilers.**

(www.vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 0):

> slogger
>
> someone who works diligently for long hours. (TFD)

Answer (score 0):

**workhorse** (*noun*):

- a person or machine that dependably performs hard work over a long period of time [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/workhorse)
- someone who does a lot of hard or boring work   [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/workhorse)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, exactly:

[***downtrodden***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/downtrodden)

> abused or oppressed by people in power

... but you'd be using it in a more literal and less figurative sense.  Worn down by work with little reward.